# How do I find an element by class name if the results don't show up conventionally?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python-3.7

In python 3, I'm attempting to enter data into a text box that has a class name.  When I inspect the site's element, I can find the class name, but when I call [find_elements_by_class_name], I get no results.

I've tried finding elements by different qualifiers, such as name and xPath, but id is not available.  No results showed up for either of these attempts.  I did find elements when I searched like this:
    element_list = DRIVER.find_elements_by_xpath('//*')
This seemed like an overly-circuitous answer.

Here's my code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
...
# DRIVER is chromedriver.exe
DRIVER.get(SITE_URL)
text_boxes = DRIVER.find_elements_by_class_name([class_name])
print(text_boxes)
```

This code yields:

```
[]
```

Here is what the element I'm trying to find looks like in inspector:

```
<input name="[name]" class="[class_name]" maxlength=20>
```

I'm expecting to find more than 0 items in [text_boxes], since I can see elements with [class_name] when I inspect the webpage.

EDIT:  Additionally, no iFrames were found by viewing page source and looking for "iframe".

Comment: look for iframes.

Answer (score 0):

Sureshmani was very close - I had the wrong frame in focus.  To rectify this, I updated my code as follows:
    from selenium import webdriver
    ...
    # DRIVER is chromedriver.exe
    DRIVER.get(SITE_URL)
    DRIVER.switch_to_frame("[frame_name]")
    text_boxes = DRIVER.find_elements_by_class_name([class_name])
    print(text_boxes)